Module with absolute Path constants within Package packaged with setuptools
I have a medium size Python package and I use setuptools to build a wheel. The package is meant to be a convenience library for a Fortran program. I now would like to define a constant which gives the Path to the Fortran executable (which lives close to my setup.py) within my Python package which I can access from any installation of my wheel. I am aware that things with resolving __file__ in a constants module won't work since this then would be the installation directory of my package.
I am aware that probably my project structure is bad and this won't arise with proper knowledge of how these things should be done. I googled around a lot but I have to say I am a bit lost here.
What I tried is to add the path to my setup.py in the long description:
setup(
    name='spinterface',
    version=VERSION,
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["spinterface.*"]),
    package_data={"":["*.json"]},
    long_description=__file__)

and then access the metadata with importlib.metadata but this gives me a path which hides the information. Like so:
/private/var/folders/dp/j32wtmvj6n9727g16dt5k1rr0000gn/T/build-via-sdist-23oojg1v/spinterface-1.0/setup.py


Use importlib.resources: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html -- This will help get you the path to where the resource you are looking for (the Fortran executable) is installed. This assumes that this resource file is correctly packaged (inside an import package, as package data, check if it is in the correct place inside the zipped wheel file).
